# When I use the noto sans cjk kr font in android edittext, the text will appear at the top

Tags: android

When I use the noto sans cjk kr font in android edittext, the text will appear at the top. But, I want to appear at center or bottom.

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ETLoginEmailInput"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:background="#00f"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:fontFamily="@font/noto_sans_cjk_kr_regular"
            android:gravity="start|bottom"
            android:hint="@string/ui_activity_login_email_input_hint"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#3f000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="1234"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/TVLoginEmailSubject"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/TVLoginEmailSubject"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```